# How do I integrate .toggle with form errors?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show a div containing other fields(only required if true) if boolean field is true, and hide the div if bool is false. Currently this code works to show and hide the div:

```js
$('.hidden-div').hide();

    $('#id_bool').change(function() {
       $('.hidden-div').toggle(this.true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

      <form method="post" novalidate>

        <div class='visible-div'>
          <input id="id_bool" type="checkbox"/>
        </div>

        # Hidden fields upon initial rendering of form,
        # but appear if bool is selected true.
        # If bool is true, these fields are required.

        <div class='hidden-div'>
          <input id="id_required" type="text" required/>
        </div>
        
        <div class='visible-div'>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
        
      </form>
```

The default value for the bool is false, so when the form is first rendered, the div is hidden. The problem arises when you check the boolean true, and try to submit the form without filling out the other fields.

The form then rehides the div and only shows errors for the normally shown fields even though the hidden fields are required. It also keeps the true value for the bool, but the hidden-div is hidden. Then, if you check the bool false, the hidden-div reappears, so the roles reverse, which is not what I want.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52570497/edit) and click the `<>` to create a [mcve] - it is not clear what you mean. If you want to hide based on initial form value, you can do `$('#id_bool').change(function() {
 $('.hidden-div').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();`

Comment: @mplungian - Edited, hope that's more clear.

Comment: Sorry no. It is not a django question, it is a jQuery only question. Please click the `<>` and post [mcve] using jQuery and HTML only, explaining expected and actual result. I have no idea what you need since the template is in the way

Comment: Ok, removed Django tag. At first I did not know what you meant because I'd never used the <> before. How's that?

Comment: @mplungjan as mentioned before, we (SO) need something more obvious than `<>` - we're close but not there yet - might need a meta suggestion/strategy - you are totally doing the right thing with your comments but on the flip side, I totally understand users' confusion - a better `<>` icon?

Comment: You have an error in your HTML code: `onclick="Are you sure?')"` There should be JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute and you have a string. That's likely causing a problem and allowing the form submission to occur, which is reloading the page.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney so they can ask. I have since you pointed this out, several times added a link to the “edit post” before I mention `<>`

Comment: ok removed onclick...

Comment: I tried to reproduce it as best I could, but in my editor the logic for the fields required if bool field true is written in python, and the rendering of field errors is Django template language.

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah I get that but perhaps if the icon is just `<>`, instead of wrapped in a piece of paper (is what it looks like its supposed to be, which actually doesn't really make sense) like the `{}` icon it would be easier to advise what to click? Anyway, not a criticism, the opposite actually, but I see the challenge

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Yes the wrapped in paper thing was what threw me for a loop.

Comment: @Whodini I've created a request here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374718/can-we-simply-the-add-snippet-stackoverflow-icon

Comment: @mplungjan https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374718/can-we-simply-the-add-snippet-stackoverflow-icon