# What is wrong with my js grammar or structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I just have this js everything fires and works:

```
$('.hidden-div').hide();

$('#id_bool').change(function() {
   $('.hidden-div').toggle(this.true);
});
```

but if I add this function directly underneath it everything stops working:

```
$('.form').on('submit', function(){
   if $('#id_bool'){
     $('.hidden-div').show();
   } else {
     $('.hidden-div').hide();
   }
});
```

What is going wrong in the second part?

Comment: what do you mean by "stops working"? Is there an error in the console? If not, what is it that behaves differently from how you would want?

Comment: because your IF syntax is wrong you need to wrap in if() { ...and also make any condition $(#id_bool) is nothing.

Comment: guys it helps when you down vote to explain why so that I can fix it or learn from it.

Comment: Chaning the question so that it has another problem should not be done. The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52572154/1) had: `if $('#id_bool') {` as problem which was answered correctly by the [answer of Omid Nikrah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52572173/1960455). But because you have corrected that problem the anwer became incorrect. If you have a further problem, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add parentheses in your if statement:

```
$('.form').on('submit', function(){
   if ($('#id_bool')){
     $('.hidden-div').show();
   } else {
     $('.hidden-div').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the grammar lesson. Still not achieving what I intend to do, but will keep at it.

Comment: @Whodini why you pass  `this.true` to `toggle` method?

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570497/how-do-i-integrate-toggle-with-form-errors

Comment: I tried this.checked but I need a hidden field to show only if a boolean is true. Still doesn't work with this.true, but I'm experimenting...

Comment: A jQuery object always evaluates as truthy, so it would never hide.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery a selector will always return a JQuery array, you need to specify a property to check.
This:

```
   if ($('#id_bool')){
```

should be:

```
  if ($('#id_bool:checked').length){
```

**Edit**:

if your id_bool has a value, that can be either true or false you can, as @Bargi mentions, use this:

```
if ($('#id_bool').val()){
```

Comment: Not really, that still produces a truthy jQuery collection. Either `$('#id_bool').is(':checked')` or `$('#id_bool').val()`.

Comment: @Bergi How about to check if field is true as opposed to checked?

Comment: @Whodini I don't even know what kind of field it is, so I can't tell

Comment: @Bergi it's a Django BooleanField with choices specified: BOOL_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'Yes'),
        (False, 'No')
        ) and it has a radio select widget, so it renders as a radio yes or no.

Comment: @Whodini https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button